# SQL copy rows from one table to another but only once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using this row to copy line from one table to another.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO edit SELECT * FROM original WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($query);
```

The first time I run this line it works fine but if Ill try to do this again it just wont copy that row.
I'll always have only one row in "edit" table with that id (even though I wanted to copy this line 3-6 times).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any constraint failing while adding at the second time. Please show the error message. I think primary key constraint is failing.

Comment: There's no error, It just won't do it. I have few lines after that code that are executed just fine. only this part doesn't work.

Comment: See if primary key or any other constraint is failing by manually inserting the records in the database.

Comment: the mysql_query functions wont stop execution on failure, you should print out the error after the query. if(!mysql_query($query)) print "Mysql error: " . mysql_error();

Comment: Well it seems to be primary key problem, I'll try to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference. The "answers" are in the comments above. The problem turned out to be a primary key problem

From Ankit Zalani:

Is there any constraint failing while adding at the second time. Please show the error message. I think primary key constraint is failing.

See if primary key or any other constraint is failing by manually inserting the records in the database.

From Me:

The mysql_query functions wont stop execution on failure, you should print out the error after the query.

```
if(!mysql_query($query)) print "Mysql error: " . mysql_error();
```